# JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null');

Tags: json, resttemplate

Requirement is to consume a webservice and persist in database. 
I wrote a stand alone class with `Resttemplate` and it works.
I used same url and same authentication mechanism + spring boot, war deployed on tomcat then when I hit the endpoint(which calls the webservice to get json output) it throws exception.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).

JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4be06322; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Can someone please assist.

Thanks.

Comment: I got this exception in different context, when I write a standalone program with RestTemplate to call webservice I get proper json format output. Same code snippet I call from a RestController it throws exception.

Comment: Looks like the data you are submitting isn't formatted properly.  You should post the code that you are using to make the call.

Comment: issue resolved now, it is because weird behavior or webservice.  I have created a standalone program with Resttemplate to consume webservice and it works fine and I get object array(json converted to java object).   but when I bundle my code in war and deploy in server and access rest end point, that time I got html response instead of json. hence it was throwing jsone parse exception. thank you.

Comment: in wht  format you want to parse data

Comment: it could also be caused by accientally trying to parse an xml file using ObjectMapper

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error many times, and it turns out that I return HTML instead of JSON (hence the `<` character error).

To fix it, you need to check if the response is JSON or HTML to avoid parsing errors.

Comment: Actually, you need to find out why you receive html and fix it he reason in your code, if possible. Most common reasons: You asked for html, you didn’t ask for JSON, or some stupid captive network inserted it’s own things into an http (not https) resource.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already said in a comment, the reason your parser was complaining about a '<' character, was that the webservice returned HTML instead of JSON.